# average daily amount from timestamps in php

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp

I have a mysql database with 2 values: a timestamp, and an amount
How would I go about calculating an average for, say, every wednesday?

I would first have to see how many unique wednesdays are mentioned, then see how much the total value is for each specific wednesday (there can be multiple entries for one day, but the time of day is not relevant)
Then I would have to add up all those values, and devide them by the amount of wednesdays.

I know this is oddly specific, that's why I probably haven't found anything about it. How would I go about doing this in PHP?

Comment: I think you should do this with MySQL rather than PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a query like this to get daily averages for each weekday.

```
SELECT DAYOFWEEK(date_only), AVG(total) FROM (
    /*The subquery will return total amounts for each distinct day
      regardless of how many records there are for each day. */ 
    SELECT
        DATE(your_table.timestamp_column) as date_only, 
        SUM(your_table.amount_column) as total 
    FROM your_table 
    GROUP BY DATE(your_table.timestamp_column)) as daily_totals
GROUP BY DAYOFWEEK(date_only);
```

[`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) will take only the date part from the timestamp. Grouping by this value and using the [`SUM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) aggregate function will get you totals for each day.

[`DAYOFWEEK()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) returns a numeric value from a date representing the day of the week (1=Sunday, etc.). Grouping by this value and using the [`AVG()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) aggregate function will get you the average total for each weekday.

How to handle the results in PHP will depend on your specific needs.

Comment: Thanks to for the answer. As I'm more into PHP than mysql, this is a bit more of abracadabra to me. Would this give me an array of all the averages on every day of the week in order?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Sorry for the abracadabra. I can edit the answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

lets say you have a table with the following columns : id timestamp amount

You have to select all the rows from the table and put them in array.
Once it's done go trough the array

```
<?php
$total = 0;
$bingo = 0;
foreach($a as $i)
{
    if(date( "l" ,$i["timestamp"]) == "Wednesday")
    {
        $bingo++;
        $total += $i["amount"];
    }
}
$avg = $total/$bingo;

?>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick response, yeah, my table does have id's assigned to it. Anyway, does the date("l" part output the day of the week in text format? Because thats what I'm understanding van here.

Comment: Also, what I just thought of, say that there are two entries on the same wednesday, then it would add to $bingo twice. How would I alter this to do that?

Comment: date( "l" ,$timestamp) 
This will return the name of the day in text format

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot for the idea, I will try and fool around with this so I will get one unique entry for every day, probably something along the likes of checking If the specific date has been mentioned before.

Comment: this piece of code will count all the entries , even if there are multiple entries on the same Wednesday. To alter this first you have to set a condition which entry you want it to be counted (first, last,highest, smallest)